# How to pause Media Player of a specific app?

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I need to pause a player of a specific application - for example Spotify. But if some other player plays I would like to keep it playing and only pause the Spotify.
Is there any function how I can do it?

I ended up with possibility to pause all apps, but not the specific one.

Or other help would be if I could identify what app is currently playing a Media Player and if it is Spotify then I can pause all apps, but I will know that I stop only Spotify.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to way extensively to stop particular app player audio
If they implement music api which is directly implemented with hardware 
then if you play music in your app then its automatically stop 
with AudioManager. You can also get callback if other application play audio.

```
 private OnAudioFocusChangeListener focusChangeListener =
     new OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
         public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
                             AudioManager am =(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                    switch (focusChange) {

                           case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK) :
                           // Lower the volume while ducking.
                           mediaPlayer.setVolume(0.2f, 0.2f);
                           break;
                           case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT) :
                           pause();
                           break;

                           case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS) :
                           stop();
                           ComponentName component =new ComponentName(AudioPlayerActivity.this,MediaControlReceiver.class);
                           am.unregisterMediaButtonEventReceiver(component);
                           break;

                           case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN) :
                           // Return the volume to normal and resume if paused.
                           mediaPlayer.setVolume(1f, 1f);
                           mediaPlayer.start();
                           break;
                           default: break;
        }
    }
};
```